# Flamingo Ribbon bar - programatically set toggle button

Tags: java, swing, radiance-flamingo

I've created my lovely Flamingo ribbon bar.

During the creation process I can instruct the builder to set a toggle button as selected.

But, I can't find a way to set a toggle as selected once the app is running.

It looks like the only attribute I can change is `setEnabled()`.

Can anyone give me a pointer on how to set the toggle state on a `FlamingoCommand`that has already been built?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The builder creates a Command. You can use Command.setToggleSelected() to change the selected state. You can see that in the ButtonGroupDemo class that changes the selected state based on the presence of bold / italic / ... style in the current text pane selection.

I also don't monitor StackOverflow that often, so the best place to get answers is over at https://github.com/kirill-grouchnikov/radiance